# css column list is unordered

Tags: css, list, multiple-columns

I have a ul li, organiz in css column. Otherwise the order of my li is totally messsed up.

I would need to have in that oder:

```
1   2
3   4
5   6
7   8
```

Here is the CSS I'm using:

```
ul.pl-bxslider.pl-box-car {-moz-column-count: 2;
-moz-column-gap: 2.5em;
-webkit-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-gap: 2.5em;
 column-count: 2;
 column-gap: 2.5em;
```

I tried to add:

```
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
```

But no luck,

i also tried to add a `display:inline-block` to the li element and nothing . . .

Any help would be so amazing :)

Thank you for your time !

Comment: Can we have your code in fiddle.

Comment: You can't achieve that layout using `column-count`. It not logical, you have rows there...not columns.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `display: inline-block;`, also set `vertical-align: top;` for li and you need to set the width for ul and li.
for example:

```
ul {
  width: 500px;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 250px;
}
```

Could be in percents.

Answer (score 0):

According my previous comment - width of the li should 50%, not 100% like you set, so in yours case:

```
 ul.pl-bxslider.pl-box-car li {
   width: 50% !important;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align:top;
 }

ul.pl-bxslider.pl-box-car {
  width:100%;
}
```